# Python RuntimerError, RuntimeError('dictionary changed size during iteration')

Tags: python, dictionary, exception, iterator

When I try To Insert a key,value to a Dict, This Code will Raise ,RuntimeError('dictionary changed size during iteration')

Here is My Code:

```py
#1. Delcare the Dict val here
dict_plugin_info = {}

#2. For module.__dict__...
for name, attr in module.__dict__.items():
    if ((inspect.isclass(attr) and (name.startswith("_") or
                                    attr.__dict__.get("__module__") != module_id))):
        continue

    if inspect.isclass(attr) and issubclass(attr, PluginInterfaceBase):
        inst = attr()
        # the follow
        plugin_type = inst.plugin_type

        keys = list(dict_plugin_info.keys())
        if plugin_type not in keys:
            ###HERE RuntimeError('dictionary changed size during iteration')####
            dict_plugin_info[plugin_type] = attr
        else:
            raise MultiplePluginError("Multiple plugins Type {} Name:{}".format(
                plugin_type,
                attr.__class__.__name__))
```

I don't know how This Happened.
I search the website Most Ansower is when iterator the dict and delete key will raise the Exception. But my code is not delete the key.

Comment: Try capturing the items upfront in a container before iterating. `list(module.__dict__.items())`. That will make a new container by exhausting the `items()` iter immediately into the new container, which wont be impacted by further changes to state

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if `module.__dict__` is a reference to the variable `dict_plugin_info`.

If so, in the line `dict_plugin_info[plugin_type] = attr`, you are trying to insert a new item to `dict_plugin_info` because you have confirmed that the `plugin_type` is not in `dict_plugin_info`'s keys, which will change the dictionary's size during iteration.

```py
d = {1: 1}
for _ in d:
    # RuntimeError: dictionary changed size during iteration
    d[2] = 2
```

From the code above, we could find that not only deleting a key (not shown in this code) but also inserting a key during iteration will raise such an exception, except that the dictionary to be iterated is empty.

```py
d = dict()
for _ in d:
    d[2] = 2  # OK
```

Comment: I use the list save the key info and check the exits....and save to the dict after the loop

Comment: your method is same error,   But you mind help to me, so I use the list to save the keyinfo.                         Thank you